# difference between the data type and style in the PLC controller tag database

Tags: binary, boolean, decimal, plc

I have noticed that few of BOOL datatype tags are of Binary style (which is anticipated) and most are of Decimal (which is surprising). 
Does anyone know the difference?

Thanks,

Comment: Your question is unclear and sounds like this is associated with a vendor specific PLC (I assume RSLogix). A "controller tag database" and "datatype tags" are no general PLC concepts. Please update your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of a variable can be displayed in different **radix** representations.
For a datatype BOOL, selecting any radix binary, decimal, octal or hexadecimal will result in the display showing 0 and 1.

For datatype DINT or WORD, selecting decimal, octal or hexadecimal will result in the display showing the value in those terms.  For example, the value sixteen will be displayed in radix decimal as 16, in radix octal as 20 and in radix hexadecimal as 0F.

To answer your question, there is no useful difference in displaying radix binary or radix decimal of a variable of the datatype BOOL.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about a 61131-3 PLC programming environment, then a BOOL is actually a BYTE, where a non-zero value is TRUE (1-255), and 0 is FALSE.

However, the BOOL variable can be used directly with logical operator IF, WHILE, AND etc..:

```
===========================================================================
FUNCTION myFunction : BOOL;
VAR
    MyA : BOOL;
END_VAR
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IF MyA THEN
    // Do something
    myFunction := MyA;
END_IF
===========================================================================
```

Most implementations of 61131-3 programming languages would force a comparison operation on a BYTE type:

```
===========================================================================
FUNCTION myFunction : BOOL;
VAR
    MyA : BYTE;
END_VAR
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IF MyA > 0 THEN
    // Do something
    myFunction := BYTE_TO_BOOL(MyA);
END_IF
===========================================================================
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is regarding the difference between the datatype tag vs the representation of this data type in the PLC. The Style, whether decimal, binary or hex is how the value is going to be **represented**, whereas the real definition of the tag type is in the datatype.

Comment: **Represented** *inside the machine*, or displayed as text?  Does any industrial PLC actually "represent" a boolean as a decimal number inside the machine?  That would seem pretty pointless.